# SQL Server does not allow remote server

Tags: sql-server

I have installed SQL Server on windows xp. When I connect to server there is an error

> SQL Server does not allow remote remote connection.
>   Error 26 : error locating server/instance specified.

What do I need to configure to make the connection work?

Comment: Which **edition** and **version** of SQL Server are we talking about here??

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into the SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable/configure the type of remote connection you are looking to use.  You might also need to modify the windows firewall if you have it enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying this over a network:

- Go to Sql Sever Configuration Manager
- Click on SQL Server Network Configuration
- Click on Protocols for
- Make sure TCP/IP is enabled

Then:

- Open SQL Server Management Studio on the computer hosting the instance
- Connect to your server instance
- Right click on the server and click Properties
- Click on Connections
- Tick "Allow remote connections to this server"

Have a cup of coffee.
Profit???

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

1) Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.

2) Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please try both Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your connection string]

3) Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).

4) Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.

5) If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.